# convex sets in convex optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

How to prove that the following set is not convex?

$$M = \left\{ \mathbb{R}^{3}: x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\le 1,x_{1}+x_{3}\ge 2,x_{1} \ge 0 \right\}$$

Thanks for any help.

---

I tried to write it down as intersection of two sets $\{x_1x_2x_3 \le 1\}$
and $\{x_1+x_3 \ge 2,x_1 \ge 0\}$. The second set is convex (it is clear) and the first set is not convex. I have used theorem about level sets, the function $x_1x_2x_3$ is not convex so the level set is not convex. This is problem, it does not mean that the intersection is not convex

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: definition, but it's too complicated.

Comment: You are encouraged to include some of your working in the post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

It's important to analyze where is the "weakness" of a problem. The last two constraints are linear. If all the constraints are convex, then the intersection must be convex. The first constraint is the weakness, attack it.

Set $x_3=1$, now visualize the projected set. Prove that the projected set is not convex by constructing a pair of points in the set where its midpoint is not in the set.

It might help if you to visualize the set $xy \le 1$. Give it a try.

---

Please try the following question first:

Prove that $M_2 = \{ \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 x_2 \le 1, x_1 +1 \ge 2, x_1 \ge 0\}$ is not convex.

Comment: I tried to write it down as intersection of two sets $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\le 1$ and $x_{1}+x_{3}\ge 2,x_{1}\ge 0$. The second set is convex (it is clear) and the first set is not convex. I have used theorem about level sets, the function $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$ is not convex so the level set is not convex. This is problem, it does not mean that the intersection is not convex.

Comment: Hi, try  to answer the question that I posted first. A possible answer consist of a counter-example, of which you should verify from definition that it is not convex. Try to sketch the set $M_2$ to help you find the counterexample.

Comment: $M_{2}$ is not convex. If we join the line between $(1,1)$ and $(2,1/2)$ the line is not included in the set $M_{2}$. However, it is not helpful, we do not know the bourdary of the set $M$ so it is not able to find any counter-example.

Comment: Good progress! Can you verify if the point $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,\frac12, 1)$ works for $M$?

Comment: It is easy to prove now, for $\lambda \in (0,1)$ $\lambda (1,1,1) + (1-\lambda ) (2,1/2,1)$ is not in $M$. Thanks for the help and patience.

Comment: congrats, actually for the purpose of counter example, you don't have to prove for the every $\lambda \in (0,1)$, you can pick a particular $\lambda$, say $\frac12$ and you are done.

Comment: To emphasize the last point: to prove a set _not_ convex, you need just one counterexample to the convexity property, and a counterexample consists of just three collinear points.